# Calculate the amount of substance of an isotope based on the percent composition

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, isotope

> Calculate the amount of substance of $\ce{^37Cl}$ in a $\pu{42.3 g}$ sample of $\ce{Cl}$ containing $24.00\%~\ce{^37Cl}$ and $76.00\%~ \ce{^35Cl}.$
>   Given the atomic masses $m(\ce{Cl}) =\pu{35.45 amu}$, $m(\ce{^35Cl}) =\pu{34.97 amu}$, and $m(\ce{^37Cl}) =\pu{36.97 amu}$.

I know you would multiply $\pu{42.3 g}$ by $0.240$ to get $\pu{10.2 g}$ of $\ce{^37Cl}$, but my teacher says you then divide by the atomic mass of $\ce{Cl}$ rather than $\ce{^37Cl}$. That is the part that confuses me, she says it is because

> You don't know what those $\pu{10.2 g}$ are made of, so you need to use the atomic mass of $\ce{Cl}$.

Comment: Your teacher  is wrong. You know precisely that 24% are $\ce{^37 Cl}$, as this is given in the question. Also not that amu is a deprecated unit and it should be replaced by u, the unified atomic mass unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have given an accurate account then your teacher is mistaken. We've all gotten confused while trying to talk and think at the same time. 
\begin{align}
\pu{42.3 g} \ce{Cl}\cdot 0.24\frac{m(\ce{^37Cl})}{m(\ce{Cl})} 
&= \pu{10.2 g} \ce{^37Cl} \\
\implies
\frac{\pu{10.2 g}~ \ce{^37Cl}}{\pu{36.97 g//mol}\ce{^37Cl}} &= \pu{0.276 mol}
\end{align}